# How can I average the data from text file?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file with two columns and I want to average the second column, while ignoring the first one. I'm new to programming, I hope you can help.

[Input File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeQ1T.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `pandas`?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t") #assuming you have a tab (\t) separated file
df["xy"].mean()
```